# How to prepare an emulsion (compounds in wt%)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, nanotechnology

I am trying to replicate an experiment to generate microparticles but I found myself confused about how to prepare the ingredients as some need to be weighed and dissolved before and I think the author is referring to weight/weight percentage. I would like to know if the g of mass synthesis and polymeric content are informative or not.

I would really appreciate any insight you have.

[image]

Comment: The distinction made in the table is confusing as for I do not see which info it does provide. Moreover why the sum doesn't amount to 100 is a mystery to me. I won't be able to follow the table :( if not interpreting and taking everithing in grams and using the same proportions (but it won't be m/m %)

Comment: @Alchimista. I get your point. However, I do not understand why the author labeled this table as recipe...